# Where can I find the pci_find_device() declaration building a network driver on Debian Stretch?

Tags: linux-kernel, debian-stretch, network-driver

I am trying to build a network driver. However, when I try to build it says:

```
error: implicit declaration of function ‘pci_find_device
```

Here is my driver:

```c
#define REALTEK_VENDER_ID  0x10EC
#define REALTEK_DEVICE_ID   0x8139

#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/stddef.h>
#include <linux/pci.h>

int init_module(void)
{
    struct pci_dev *pdev;
    pdev = pci_find_device(REALTEK_VENDER_ID, REALTEK_DEVICE_ID, NULL);
    if(!pdev)
        printk("<1>Device not found\n");
    else
        printk("<1>Device found\n");
    return 0;
}
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Here is my Makefile

```
obj-m += ethDriver.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

When I build, I get the following errors:

```
ethDriver.c: In function ‘init_module’:
/home/xxx/ethDriver/ethDriver.c:13:12: error: implicit declaration of function ‘pci_find_device’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
     pdev = pci_find_device(REALTEK_VENDER_ID, REALTEK_DEVICE_ID, NULL);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/xxx/ethDriver/ethDriver.c:13:10: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     pdev = pci_find_device(REALTEK_VENDER_ID, REALTEK_DEVICE_ID, NULL);
          ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-3-common/scripts/Makefile.build:315: recipe for target '/home/xxx/ethDriver/ethDriver.o' failed
make[4]: *** [/home/xxx/ethDriver/ethDriver.o] Error 1
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-3-common/Makefile:1507: recipe for target '_module_/home/xxx/ethDriver' failed
make[3]: *** [_module_/home/xxx/ethDriver] Error 2
Makefile:150: recipe for target 'sub-make' failed
make[2]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-3-amd64'
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pci_find_device()` function was removed in kernel v2.6.34.

From [`Documentation/PCI/pci.rst`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/481ed297d900af0ce395f6ca8975903b76a5a59e/Documentation/PCI/pci.rst):

> **Obsolete functions**
>
> There are several functions which you might come across when trying to
>   port an old driver to the new PCI interface. They are no longer
>   present in the kernel as they aren't compatible with hotplug or PCI
>   domains or having sane locking.
>
> ```
> pci_find_device() Superseded by pci_get_device()
> pci_find_subsys() Superseded by pci_get_subsys()
> pci_find_slot()   Superseded by pci_get_domain_bus_and_slot()
> pci_get_slot()    Superseded by pci_get_domain_bus_and_slot()
> ```

You'll need to use [`pci_get_device()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.9/source/include/linux/pci.h#L1521), which should also be included in `<linux/pci.h>`.

```c
/**
 * pci_get_device - begin or continue searching for a PCI device by vendor/device id
 * @vendor: PCI vendor id to match, or %PCI_ANY_ID to match all vendor ids
 * @device: PCI device id to match, or %PCI_ANY_ID to match all device ids
 * @from: Previous PCI device found in search, or %NULL for new search.
 *
 * Iterates through the list of known PCI devices.  If a PCI device is
 * found with a matching @vendor and @device, the reference count to the
 * device is incremented and a pointer to its device structure is returned.
 * Otherwise, %NULL is returned.  A new search is initiated by passing %NULL
 * as the @from argument.  Otherwise if @from is not %NULL, searches continue
 * from next device on the global list.  The reference count for @from is
 * always decremented if it is not %NULL.
 */
struct pci_dev *pci_get_device(unsigned int vendor, unsigned int device,
                   struct pci_dev *from)
{
    return pci_get_subsys(vendor, device, PCI_ANY_ID, PCI_ANY_ID, from);
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(pci_get_device);
```

PS: your `#define` has a typo, it should probably be `VENDOR`, not `VENDER`.